# How to get active Lightning app?

Tags: app

This is supposed to be sort of official method:

```
public static String getActiveTab(){
    String tabLabel;
    for(Schema.DescribeTabSetResult i : Schema.describeTabs()) {
        if(i.isSelected()) {
            tabLabel = i.getLabel();
            break;
        }
    }
    return tabLabel;
}
```

However what is returns is App that I have selected in Classic. It seems App selection between modes is completely different. I think it has to do something with how Lightning Apps is actually different metadata type.

FWIW I did notice that switching from Lightning to Classic in a scratch org, occasionally defaults me to Service Console app. When snippet above is executed in Lightning, by default it returns 'Service Console'.

Comment: Had brainfart and had typed in "in Apex" when meant in "Classic". When executing from Classic context result is not the same as executing in Lightning context.

Comment: Probably has to do something with Lightning apps being essentially different type of an app / metadata.

Comment: I'd suggest asking questions to those who find this unclear...

Comment: I'm voting to leave this post closed as it doesn't contain a question. If you **edit** the contents to at least ask something, it seems likely to be on topic.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've rewritten the question, hope this time it's more clear.