# How does one get the active app in Lightning?

Tags: apex, lightning

In Classic, one can use code like this to determine the app the current user is currently working in

```
public static String getActiveTab(){
    String tabLabel;
    for(Schema.DescribeTabSetResult i : Schema.describeTabs()) {
        if(i.isSelected()) {
            tabLabel = i.getLabel();
            break;
        }
    }
    return tabLabel;
}
```

In Lightning, however, this code will return the current (or last) app the user is working with (or was working with) when the user is in Classic. Is there a way to identify the currently selected app in Lightning?

Comment: Hey, I had a same question which was unfortunately closed: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230543/how-to-get-active-lightning-app
I've also heard from Salesforce internally that bug was raised but nothing more after it.